# From which table does magento extract the shipping and handling information in Order page on admin panel?

Tags: magento

Previously I thought that the "price" shown in the order page under "Shipping and Handling Information" block in magento's admin panel is retrieved from "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate" table but when I changed the value of price in the database manually it doesn't reflect any changes, from that i concluded that the price is not retrieved from that table.

Can anyone help me to understand this?

I have attached the screenshot to make clear what I am talking about.

[image: Order Page]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orders data are saved in database tables `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item`

Check columns `base_shipping_amount` & `shipping_amount` in `sales_flat_order` table

Answer (score 1):

To update the Shipping / Flat Rate, why are you modifying the DB, you can achieve this from the admin section.

Update the values their.

System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Flat Rate.

[image]

In case you need to update it for a particular order then you can use tables suggested by Dushyant Joshi

Comment: Deepika, he is asking about from where "Shipping & Handling Information" is comming in an admin order view